# Web.config authorization: 'deny users' tag disallows even authorized users

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I have a Web.config file which authenticates a user logging into a webpage, based on his role.

The current implementation is as follows:

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles = "BUILTIN\Administrators" />
  <allow roles = "PRIVILEGED" />
  <allow roles = "NON_PRIVILEGED" />
  <deny users = "*" />
</authorization>
```

From my understanding, the above implementation should allow users who are Administrators, or those who belong to either of the roles 'PRIVILEGED' or 'NON_PRIVILEGED'. The remaining users, who do not possess any of the above roles should be denied access, the behavior of which is implented by the tag  `<deny users = "*" />`

But, I found that the authorized users (who possess the required roles of Administrators/Privileged/Non_privileged) are being denied access to the web page with the message "404-Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials"

When I remove the tag `<deny users = "*" />` from the config file, I could see that the authorized users are able to access the webpage without any problems.The config file looks as follows after removing the `<deny users = "*" />`

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles = "BUILTIN\Administrators" />
  <allow roles = "PRIVILEGED" />
  <allow roles = "NON_PRIVILEGED" />
</authorization>
```

So, the issue is with the tag `<deny users = "*" />` , which seems to be denying access to all users, irrespective of the roles they possess.

From the very basic knowledge I have of web configuration and IIS, I can say `<deny users = "*" />` is not incorrectly used in the config file. So,I don't have a clue as to why it is denying access to all users.

Currently, we are using IIS version 7.

Answer (score 0):

The default access for any user not matched by an `<allow>` tag is to deny.

The point of `<deny>` is to override an `<allow>`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the role manager to be enabled?

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: I have placed the 'deny users' tag before all the 'allow' tags, but still, the issue persists and the authorized users are being denied access.

Comment: I apologize you actually had it in the correct order the first time. Move it back like you had it.